# How to implement docker image with google cloud datastore emulator and java

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-datastore

I need to create test docker image with google cloud datastore emulator and java application. Java app use emulator to store test data. How should i create this image? Should i use FROM openjdk:8 or FROM google/cloud-sdk:latest?

Answer (score 1):

this is the config i used to create a datastore emulator

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk:latest
ENV CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT project-id

ENTRYPOINT ["gcloud", "beta", "emulators", "datastore", "start",\
            "--host-port", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--no-store-on-disk", \
            "--consistency=1" ]
EXPOSE 8000
```

build steps:

1. Build the image using:

   ```
   docker build -t datastore-emulator:latest .
   ```
2. start a docker container:

   ```
   docker run -p 8000:8000 datastore-emulator:latest
   ```

set the application to use the emulator using:

```
export DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8000
```

Comment: question was about image with gcloud and java in one container

Comment: I misunderstood the question. To be clear, you are hoping to run a java application and datastore emulator in one container?